# Storing a (string,integer) tuple more efficiently and apply binary search

Tags: java, optimization, storage, binaryfiles, binary-search

**Introduction**

We store tuples `(string,int)` in a binary file. The string represents a word (no spaces nor numbers). In order to find a word, we apply binary search algorithm, since we know that all the tuples are sorted with respect to the word.

In order to store this, we use [writeUTF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)) for the string and [writeInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeInt(int)) for the integer. Other than that, let's assume for now there are no ways to distinguish between the start and the end of the tuple unless we know them in advance.

**Problem**

> When we apply binary search, we get a position (i.e. (a+b)/2) in the file, which we can read using methods in [Random Access File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), i.e. we can read the byte at that place. However, since we can be in the middle of the word, we cannot know where this words starts or finishes.

**Solution**

Here're two possible solutions we came up with, however, we're trying to decide which one will be more space efficient/faster.

- **Method 1:** Instead of storing the `integer` as a number, we thought to store it as a string (using eg. [writeChars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeChars(java.lang.String)) or [writeUTF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String))), because in that case, we can insert a **null character** in the end of the tuple. That is, we can be sure that none of the methods used to serialize the data will use the null character, since the information we store (numbers and digits) have higher ASCII value representations.
- **Method 2:**  We keep the same structure, but instead we separate each tuple with 6-8 (or less) bytes of random noise (same across the file). In this case, we assume that words have a low entropy, so it's very unlikely they will have any signs of randomness. Even if the `integer` may get 4 bytes that are exactly the same as those in the random noise, the additional two bytes that follow will not (with high probability).

Which of these methods would you recommend? Is there a better way to store this kind of information. Note, we cannot serialize the entire file and later de-serialize it into memory, since it's very big (and we are not allowed to).

Comment: How big is "very big"? how "big" do you need to support? What's a typical string length, and what's the absolute minimum & maximum lengths?

Comment: @Amit, it's less than 200MB. Max 20 chars for a word.

Comment: ohhh, so not that big at all, great!

Comment: since it's an assignment, we should pretend it's big and that it cannot be loaded into memory all at once, i.e.we have to work with the file.

Comment: Ohhhh... assignment... as in homework?

Comment: correct. however, this question is not part of the homework, it's just out of curiosity.

Comment: **Method 3:** Implement a [Binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree).

Comment: @Andreas - how is a BST related? the assumption is that it's impossible to read the full dataset to memory...

Comment: @Amit So?? Who says a BST has to be entirely in memory? How do you think RDBMS indexes work? Granted, they are rarely "binary", but it's the same concept. This question is basically asking how to implement a fast disk-based lookup of sorted data, which is exactly what regular a SQL INDEX does.

Comment: @Andreas - you're right, I misunderstood you, but it's a legit option. Why not post an answer?

Comment: @Amit Because OP's comment "it's less than 200MB" makes it sound like there's no need for disk-based binary search, so I was basically asking OP if a Binary search tree solution was considered as an alternative to a binary search of an ordered index, whether disk-based or memry-based. I guess that suggesting a third method to consider was not clear on my intent.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're trying to optimize for speed & space (in that order).

I'd use a different layout, built from 2 files:

1. **Interger + Index file**
   Each "*record*" is exactly 8 bytes long, the lower 4 are the integer value for the record, and the upper 4 bytes are an integer representing the offset for the record in the other file (the *characters file*).
2. **Characters file**
   Contiguous file of characters (UTF-8 encoding or anything you choose). "*Records*" are not separated, not terminated in any way, simple 1 by 1 characters. For example, the records `Good`, `Hello`, `Morning` will look like `GoodHelloMorning`.

To iterate the dataset, you iterate the integer/index file with direct access (`recordNum * 8` is the byte offset of the record), read the integer and the characters offset, plus the character offset of the next record (which is the 4 byte integer at `recordNum * 8 + 12`), then read the string from the characters file between the offsets you read from the index file. Done!

Comment: And, when building the files, be careful to treat the characters file as variable length byte sequences, with the length being dependent on the character encoding used (which won't necessarily equal the `String.length()`).

Comment: If the index file only gives the offset to the text in the characters file, and the characters file doesn't have length, separator, or terminators, how do you know the length of the text referenced by the index file?

Comment: @Andreas - as I explained, the idea is to read the offset of the record **and** the offset of the next record ( of course if there is no next record the length is implicit).

Comment: Sorry, I got confused by your example. If this is supposed to be a binary search of an "array" (index file, fixed record length), then the strings should be in alphabetical order, but your example shows `HelloMorningGood`, which is not in alphabetical order, implying that text is not necessarily in the same order as index, meaning that the offset of the next index entry is *not* the end of the previous index entry.

Comment: @Andreas - I actually missed the fact that the records are already alphabetically sorted, and just assumed there's "some" order to them (perhaps in combination with the integer), but you're right, I need to fix the answer...

Comment: If they weren't sorted, you couldn't do a binary search.

Comment: @Andreas - sorting is not necessarily alphabetically, and not necessarily ascending (though in this case, that's what the OP apparently wanted).

Comment: BTW You only need to store the end of each record and the first record you might assume to start at 0. This could complicate the code so storing the end and leaving the first index at zero would simplify the code. Note: if you add a header later, you could use that approach for the header.

Answer (score 1):

> it's less than 200MB. Max 20 chars for a word.

So why bother? Unless you work on some severely restricted system, load everything into a `Map<String, Integer>` and get a few orders of magnitude speed up.

But let's say, I'm overlooking something and let's continue.

---

> **Method 1:** Instead of storing the integer as a number, we thought to store it as a string (using eg. writeChars or writeUTF), because in that case, we can insert a null character

You don't have to as you said that your word contains no numbers. So you can always parse things like `0124some456word789` uniquely.

The efficiency depends on the distribution. You may win a factor of 4 (single digit numbers) or lose a factor of 2.5 (10-digit numbers). You could save something by using a higher base. But there's the storage for the string and it may dominate.

> **Method 2:** We keep the same structure, but instead we separate each tuple with 6-8 (or less) bytes of random noise (same across the file).

This is too wasteful. Using four zeros between the data byte would do:

- Find a sequence of at least four zeros.
- Find the last zero.
- That's the last separator byte.

**Method 3:** Using some hacks, you could ensure that the number contains no zero byte (either assuming that it doesn't use the whole range or representing it with five bytes). Then a single zero byte would do.

**Method 4:** As disk is organized in blocks, you should probably split your data into 4 KiB blocks. Then you can add some time header allowing you quick access to the data (start indexes for the 8th, 16th, etc. piece of data). The range between e.g., the 8th and 16th block should be scanned sequentially as it's both simpler and faster than binary search.